# Can't export GPX from RunKeeper in BaseCamp

Tags: gpx, garmin

I exported a GPX file from the [Runkeeper website](https://runkeeper.com). The file itself seems to be valid and I was able to use it in [GeoSetter](http://www.geosetter.de). I was also able to open it using [ITN Converter](http://www.benichou-software.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4&Itemid=2&lang=en) which was allegedly a recommended *solution* according to a post on [gpsreview.net](http://forums.gpsreview.net/discussion/25800/gpx-file-not-readable-on-basecamp).

I tried to compare the file from RunKeeper to one generated by BaseCamp and the only difference I was able to identify was that BasCamp added gpxx:TrackExtension and gpxtrkx:TrackStatsExtension sections.

The structure of the RunKeeper file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx
  version="1.1"
  creator="Runkeeper - http://www.runkeeper.com"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"
  xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1">
<trk>
  <name><![CDATA[Rowing 6/8/14 9:44 am]]></name>
  <time>2014-06-08T13:44:31Z</time>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="46.883792000" lon="-71.366407000"><ele>148.2</ele><time>2014-06-08T13:44:31Z</time></trkpt>
[...]
<trkpt lat="46.883627000" lon="-71.367274000"><ele>148.0</ele><time>2014-06-08T15:32:41Z</time></trkpt>
</trkseg>
</trk>
</gpx>
```

What is wrong with this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems BaseCamp doesn't like having <time> tag right inside the <trk> element. Removing it allowed the track to be imported.